# c++ win32api and the use of a char[] split

Tags: c++, winapi, split, char

Iam trying to make a small win32api program in Visual C++ 2010 express.

The function of the program will be that it recieves basically a string from the serial port, the string is devided by ; (i can choose whatever delimter i want though)..
The idea is to split that up and put everything in a edit control for every section.

But, the ReadFile function will only take a char[] array, wich should be no problem, as SendMessageA also only takes char[] array. So no conversion needed.

But i just cannot find a way to split this upp accordingly. The best functions for this seems to be for everything else than just char[] ironically..

Anyone have any suggestions for this?

Comment: Sounds like something you could do with [`strtok`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/).

Comment: You better use state machine to extract values from serial port

Comment: Uh... `SendMessageA()`? How are you trying to use it?

Comment: You can always convert the character array to std::string or whatever.

Comment: @Michael Thanks, will have a look in to that..

Comment: @andlabs 'code' SendMessageA(FLSPEED,WM_SETTEXT,NULL,(LPARAM)str); 'code' If i didnt use it, chinese signs shows up in the edit control..

Comment: @HarryJohnston Yes, but wouldnt i have to convert it back to character array again to send it to the edit box? It could work, but seems a bit wasteful though?

Comment: Not particularly.  Unless you're writing code for a ZX81, the time taken by a couple of string conversions is negligible.  (If you were trying to do this a million times a second you might need to worry.  But you'll be waiting on the serial port anyway, it is *much* slower than the CPU.)

Comment: @HarryJohnston Yes, you are right, but the hunt for slim is always on :) Will there be any problems converting it back to a char array again afterwards? Since the edit control wants that..

Comment: You get Chinese characters because your project is set to use Unicode Windows API functions by default. That is unrelated to serial input, that is only about GUI elements and some other Windows API functions.

Comment: @andlabs Yes i know this. But im not sure why you brought it up?

Comment: I wasn't sure why you were using that function; your answer cleared it up.

Comment: @andlabs, oh okey! thank you anyway.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Hello, again! I just cant seem to find any nice way to convert the std::string back to lparam/char*?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3372cxcy.aspx

Comment: Yep, c_str() solved it :)

Answer (score 0):

Solution was to first convert the char array from ReadFile to a std:string. extract what is needed, and convert that back again to a character array using c_str()..

Thanks everyone for your help